# Efficiently storing a matrix with many zeros, dynamically

Tags: c++, arrays, optimization

**Background:**

I'm working in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

I recall there being a method to efficiently (*memory-wise*) store "arrays" (where an array might be made of `std::vector`'s, `std::set`'s, etc... I don't care how, so long as it is memory efficient **and** I'm able to check the value of each element) of `0's` and `1's` (or, equivalently, truth/false, etc), wherein there is a disproportionate number of one or the other (e.g. mostly zeroes).

---

I've written an algorithm, which populates an "array" (currently, a `vector<vector<size_t>>`) with `0's` and `1's` according to some function. For these purposes, we can more-or-less consider it as being done randomly. The array is to be quite large (of variable size... on the order of `1000` columns, and `1E+8` or more rows), and always rectangular.

There need be this many data points. In the best of times, my machine becomes quickly resource constrained and slows to a crawl. At worst, I get `std::bad_alloc`.

Putting aside what I intend to do with this array, what is the most efficient (memory-wise) way to store a **rectangular array of `1's` and `0's` (or `T`/`F`, etc), where there are mostly `1`'s or `0`'s (and I know which is most populous)?**.

Note that the array need be created "dynamically" (i.e. one element at a time), elements must maintain their location, and I need only to check the value of individual elements after creation. I'm concerned about memory footprint, nothing else.

Comment: Consider using a matrix library like Eigen or Armadillo which will have all this built in

Comment: I would just store them as bits with [bitset](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-bitset-and-its-application/), that way you can call the `count()` method which returns # of on bits, or set bits, and even flip them. As for the memo-ization, that's best served when writing a recursive algorithm. So you could keep a memoized queue of pair<T x,T y> of recent bit flips, checking the queue first each time. Or try to arrange the bits in a heap, but there's usually a tradeoff between slowdown during sort, during search, during insert, or during removal depending on the data structure chosen.

Comment: You could even generate bitmask to do bitwise operations for rapid checks, which I believe is the least computationally expensive.

Comment: @Xinthral That looks perfect, never heard of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is known as a sparse array or matrix.

```
std::set<std::pair<int,int>> bob;
```

If you want 7,100 to be 1, just `bob.insert({7,100});`.  Missing elements are 0.  You can use `bob.count({3,7})` for a 0/1 value if you like.

Now looping over both columns are rows is tricky; easiest is to make 2 sets each backwards.

If you have no need to loop in order, use an unordered set instead.